# Permission Denied Error with subprocess.call()

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Im trying to convert some nrrd files to Dicom files,and i have this code snippet

```
NRRD_TO_DICOM = '/mnt/sdc1/user/6363/'
def NRRDToDICOM(filename, output_folder_name):
    subprocess.call([NRRD_TO_DICOM, filename, output_folder_name])

NRRDToDICOM('ARTERIAL.nrrd', '/mnt/sdc1/user/6363/ARTERIAL/')
```

I tried running this from my jupyter notebook,but it gives me

```
 PermissionError                           

Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-5ee279d7c7db> in <module>()
      3     subprocess.call([NRRD_TO_DICOM, filename, output_folder_name])
      4 
----> 5 NRRDToDICOM('ARTERIAL.nrrd', '/mnt/sdc1/Ryan/6363/ARTERIAL/')

<ipython-input-6-5ee279d7c7db> in NRRDToDICOM(filename, output_folder_name)
      1 NRRD_TO_DICOM = '/mnt/sdc1/Ryan/6363/'
      2 def NRRDToDICOM(filename, output_folder_name):
----> 3     subprocess.call([NRRD_TO_DICOM, filename, output_folder_name])
      4 
      5 NRRDToDICOM('ARTERIAL.nrrd', '/mnt/sdc1/Ryan/6363/ARTERIAL/')

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

After which i saved the saved the file as a `py` file and ran it from the terminal after doing

`chmod +x /mnt/sdc1/user/6363/ARTERIAL/`

`chmod +x  /mnt/sdc1/user/6363/`

But the same error persists,
Any suggestions on how i may fix this will be very helpful,Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to reduce this to an [mcve] without any exception handling so you can see exactly what's happening and get a traceback. We can see even less than you can from this.

Comment: Alright ,Give me a sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to run `/mnt/sdc1/user/6363/` as the name of a command, but obviously, it isn't one.

It's not clear what you are attempting to actually run, but this is not the right way to do that at all.

The first item in the list you pass as the first argument to `subprocess.Popen()` and its various convenience wrappers needs to be an executable *file* just like you would need to type a command, not a directory name, at the shell prompt.

I'm guessing your code should look something like

```
def NRRDToDICOM(filename, output_folder_name):
    subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/nrrdtodicom', filename, output_folder_name])
```

where the path to the executable might not be necessary if it's already on your `PATH` (as it probaby should be -- I mainly put in the `/usr/bin/` to make it really explicit that we are talking about that type of thing), and you can of course save it in a variable if you absolutely insist, but that seems like a weird thing to want here (though if a command with the required API could be installed under a number of different names, perhaps then it would make sense to make it configurable or at least easy to change).

Comment: Oh Okay ,Im passing it a directory ,thats where im going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Use `-R` to recurse every level directories:

```
chmod +x -R /mnt/sdc1/user/6363/ARTERIAL/
```

Comment: let me check this

Comment: Im still getting the same error,Am i doing something wrong here@aircraft

Comment: Your given command are only for the directory, you see my edited answer.

Comment: Huh? No, the `-R` would already make it traverse the entire tree; the wildcard you added just makes it (a tiny bit) slower, and makes it miss any directory entries which start with a dot.

Comment: when i try the suggested edit i get the following error `'chmod: cannot access '/mnt/sdc1/Ryan/6363/ARTERIAL/*': No such file or directory
`