# Got "access denied" error trying to access another drive via subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, windows, permissions

I am trying to learn os.system and subprocess to control cmd with Python.

I tried this:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
import subprocess

subprocess.call('i:')
```

I got an "access denied" error.

I also tried

```
subprocess.Popen('i:')
```

and got an same error.

My "i" drive is not a special drive. it's just a USB drive.

How can I fix this?

This is not a duplicate of [Permission Denied Error with subprocess.call()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699437/permission-denied-error-with-subprocess-call) as that question is about Linux and I am working on Windows.

### --------------------------

It is not really solution, but it worked.
I moved my .py file to I drive and run.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permission Denied Error with subprocess.call()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699437/permission-denied-error-with-subprocess-call)

Comment: It seems for linux... and I am on windows. sorry

Comment: Other drives i.e. c drive  are working fine?

Comment: I tried now, and answer is yes. subprocess.Popen('dir', shell=true) is worked, but not in I drive